# How to decide which version of Google Play services to use?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am working on an Android application which supports Android version 14 and above. I have compiled my application against Android version 21.
I have used Google Play Services 7.0.0. The application works fine on Android 21. But when I run the application on Android version 19, it throws the following exception

**Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7095000 but found 6183036**

So, I want to know what should be the version of Google Play  that I should include in my application so that it works fine on Android 14 and above.

Comment: If you include version 7.0.0 of the library with your app, the device has to have at least that version of Google Play services installed. It's not dependent on Android version of that device. Check for Play services updates via store on your KitKat device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to find an answer to your question using a wrong approach.

The version of the Google Play Services that you want to include depends on the APIs your application implements. Picking a version based on the device you want to support will affect your application performance in a negative way.

**Nearby Connections API**, **Places API** are added in the **Google Play services 7.0**. If your application is using any of those or other APIs added in this version of Play Services then, these features may not work if you specify a lesser version in the Gradle files.

Similarly, **Mobile Vision API**, **Nearby Messages** were introduced in the Google Play Services version 7.8. There is no way you can implement them by including an earlier version of Play Services even if you want to support Android 2.3 devices.

**Maps and Location Based Services** services had been updated in many Play Services versions. Each update has added a small feature to it and improved overall battery efficiency, responsiveness. The version number you are using will affect the battery life ...

In every update to the Google Play Services existing versions, new APIs are released and old ones are improved. Consider the APIs your application is implementing then decide which version of the Play Services you want your users to update so that they can use your application smoothly.

Many Android users regularly update their Google Play Services. Even if the user has a KitKat device or Ice Cream Sandwich they could have updated their Google Play Services to the latest 7.8 version or to an intermediate version.

Comment: And if the user does not have the required Play Services version then ?

Comment: Note that all devices, regardless of whether they are running a new or old version of the OS, would normally automatically upgrade to the latest version of Google Play Services when it is available.  However, there are exceptions such as devices which don't have enough free storage to download the upgrade.  But I'd suggest always using the latest version of Google Play Services, since most users will have it.

Comment: @user3213851 If the user doesn't have the required Play Services then your application crashes when performing an operation (eg: when clicking a button to get location details). But if you check for the availability of Play Services at the start of the activity (or before using Play Services) then the user will be shown an error dialog to get (or update) the Play Services from the Play Store.

Comment: @SrikarReddy - Is there any blog where I can find all information about which APIs were included in which Google Play Services version?

Comment: @Gurpreet This is the closest I could find https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases. Hope it helps.

Comment: After the release of nearby connections 2.0 in 2017, according to this post (https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/07/31/google-announces-nearby-connections-api-v2-0-full-offline-functionality-bandwidth-less-latency/), minimum Google Play Service required is version 11.0. The only problem is that they point to the official docs as a reference, but the official docs say nothing on min Google Play Services version or min android OS version.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the `minimum sdk` version in `gradle(app)` file to run your application in lower versions of android.

Comment: though it depends on the lib he is using ,